# Interesting topological groups that aren't manifolds?

Tags: topological-groups

Does anyone know of examples of "pathological" topological groups that are actually used? I am particularly interested in infinite non-Hausdorff examples.

Comment: $p$-adic Lie groups and profinite groups often pop up in number theory.

Comment: The Zariski topology is used in algebraic geometry and it almost always is non-Hausdorff.

Comment: And in fact, the Zariski topology on a scheme (including "generic points") is almost always not even $T_1$.

Comment: There is no reason to study topological groups that are not Hausdorff: their study immediately reduces to the study of their Hausdorffification and the kernel of the map to the Hausdorffification, namely the normal subgroup given by the closure of the identity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A large and common class of topological groups that aren't Lie groups are [profinite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group). These naturally appear in [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) as Galois groups of infinite extensions, in number theory in relation to [$p$-adic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) Lie groups, and in algebraic geometry as [étale fundamental groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group).